# How to obtain stock ticker symbol from this data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, for-loop, stock

I wanted to obtain the stock ticker symbol from this data. This is the progress I made so far. Afterwards, I just ended up going in circles. I was trying to get the ticker characters together in an array like this: ['VOO', 'DIS'...]

```
var data = "VOO2.1315$232.86$23.34$496.34DIS1.94733$96.40$12.09$187.72IWM1.07511$112.56$4.24$121.01DAL5$29.55-$16.70$147.75XOM2$36.95-$29.42$73.90VYM1$69.75-$0.69$69.75SBUX1.19403$66.34$2.82$79.21HAL11$6.39$1.21$70.29SFYX9$7.61-$0.40$68.45O1$56.90$2.07$56.90WPG40$1.03-$44.80$41.20SFY6$9.06$0.00$54.36SCHA1$50.96$2.22$50.96DIG10$4.58-$5.40$45.80MO1$36.64-$2.73$36.64DVN6$6.29-$4.26$37.74CSCO1$38.82$5.99$38.82AEG14$2.62-$17.64$36.68XLE1$28.33-$1.91$28.33DOW1$28.56$5.31$28.56RDSA1$31.64$5.46$31.64CBL50$0.24-$13.86$12.14";

function tickerSep(info){
var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        if (info[i].match(/([A-Z])/g)) {
            result.push(info[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
}
tickerSep(data);
```

Comment: what is the format of your data string?

Comment: The data is copied and pasted from SoFi. I thew it into a string and attached it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `g` flag will do that for you.

```js
function tickerSep(info) {
    return info.match(/[A-Z]+/g);
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: THANK YOU, SO MUCH!

Comment: If my answer helped, can you mark it as approved so people know that the question has been answered?

Comment: No problem! It's my first time using stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick.  Let me know if you don't understand.

```js
var data = "VOO2.1315$232.86$23.34$496.34DIS1.94733$96.40$12.09$187.72IWM1.07511$112.56$4.24$121.01DAL5$29.55-$16.70$147.75XOM2$36.95-$29.42$73.90VYM1$69.75-$0.69$69.75SBUX1.19403$66.34$2.82$79.21HAL11$6.39$1.21$70.29SFYX9$7.61-$0.40$68.45O1$56.90$2.07$56.90WPG40$1.03-$44.80$41.20SFY6$9.06$0.00$54.36SCHA1$50.96$2.22$50.96DIG10$4.58-$5.40$45.80MO1$36.64-$2.73$36.64DVN6$6.29-$4.26$37.74CSCO1$38.82$5.99$38.82AEG14$2.62-$17.64$36.68XLE1$28.33-$1.91$28.33DOW1$28.56$5.31$28.56RDSA1$31.64$5.46$31.64CBL50$0.24-$13.86$12.14";

function tickerSep(info){
var result = [];
var temp = '';
var myArray = data.split('$');
var len = myArray.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
       temp ='';
       for(var j = 0;j<myArray[i].length;j++){        
        if (myArray[i][j].match(/([A-Z])/g)) {
            temp =temp + myArray[i][j];
        }
       } 
        if(temp != '')result.push(temp);
    }
    console.log(result);
}
tickerSep(data);

function tickerSep1(info) {
    return info.match(/[A-Z]+/g);
}

console.log(tickerSep1(data));
```